# I am trying to pass the parameter from a file to the shell script, but because of space it is breaking

Tags: shell

Script :

```
#script.sh
clear
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo ***********"starting shell script"************
echo ----------------------------------------------
ls

curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8081/adddetails"  --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{ \"batch_id\": \"$1\", \"modality\": {     \"modality\" : \"$2\" }, \"start_time\": \"$3\"} ] } "

echo \"$1\"
echo \"$2\"
echo \"$3\"
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo ***********"ending shell script"************
echo ----------------------------------------------
```

My input file from where I a taking parameter:
`1 a 2015-12-31 18:30:00`

here `$3` should be `2015-12-31 18:30:00` but because of space it is breaking.
I tried many escape characters but nothing is working

I ran below command:

```
bash scripts.sh $(cat inputs.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shell's default behavior is to split args by space, so not much to do there, your `$3` argument will be the date only.

What you could do is create a variable inside your script concatenating the variables you want to handle as a single value.

```
DATETIME="$3 $4"
echo $DATETIME
```

Another option would be to pass your arguments with quotes to the command:

```
./script.sh arg1 arg2 "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"
```

But this approach doesn't work if you are passing the arguments from a file.

Comment: Thanks alot for all your responses.. However I have changed the wait I was accepting inputs, now I am accepting the api in Json file. and here is the way to call it.

Comment: '#script.sh
clear
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo ***********"starting shell script"************
echo ----------------------------------------------


curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8081/adddetails" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data @user.json


echo ----------------------------------------------
echo ***********"ending shell script"************
echo ----------------------------------------------

#cat scripts.sh'

Answer (score 1):

The script itself looks fine, the trouble is with the way you are calling it.  `bash` has no way of reading your mind to determine that you want the 3rd and 4th columns of your input to be merged into a single argument.  Perhaps you could try separating the arguments by tab instead of spaces in inputs.txt and specify `tab` in IFS.  Something like:

```
$ cat -tve inputs.txt 
1^Ia^I2015-12-31 18:30:00$
$ (IFS=$'\t'; ./script.sh $(cat inputs.txt) )
```

Another option (which doesn't require the subshell or modification of the input file) which seems a bit cleaner is:

```
$ read a b date < inputs.txt 
$ ./script.sh "$a" "$b" "$date"
```

With this particular example, you don't need to set IFS because `read` will concat all of the remaining arguments into the final variable, but you may want to use a similar technique as above and do:

```
$ IFS=$'\t' read a b date c < inputs.txt 
$ ./script.sh "$a" "$b" "$date"
```

For example, this would be necessary if there were more inputs on the line after the date, and this would rely on modifying the input file to use `tab` as the field separator.